# Accessing listview index in an extensible QML application

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm doing an extensible QML application, it means that some of the components are loaded according to the "plugins" loaded on the application.

One of the situations is the following.

I've a ListView, and some of the elements shown on the ListView delegate are loaded based on the plugins.
To create the component/object I use the functions:
**Qt.createComponent** **and component.createObject**

It works great, and I can see and interact with the qml components loaded.

However, for some of the features I need to change the listview index from inside a plugin qml file (that is loaded on a delegated), but the index is not accessible from there, and I get a simple
**index is not defined**
When trying to.

The code is on github: The extension file is this one: https://github.com/danielfranca/procrastinationkiller/blob/master/extensions/timerTasks/taskRow.qml

The specific part I need to access the index is on the **clicked** signal of mousearea of element with id **playpause**.

I also tried finding the ListView element, and calling the function **indexAt** with the x, y mouse coordinates, but it's always returning 0.

The specific code that loads the component is this one:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
                        addTaskLayout.inputObjects = Extensions.createExtensionComponent("extraInput.qml", addTaskLayout);
                    }
```

And this function is a javascript function that is in this file: https://github.com/danielfranca/procrastinationkiller/blob/master/extensions.js

Let me know if you need more details, and I would love to understand why QML don't expose the index to loaded components and why it can't find the index even with x,y coordinates.

I'm using Qt5.4, Ubuntu 14.10, Qt Creator 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simpler than I expected.
The best way seems to be sending the index as a parameter when creating the component.
In my case the call became:

```
Extensions.createExtensionComponent("taskRow.qml", row, {"model":tasksModel.get(index), "index": index});
```

And in my plugin component I create a property with the name index as follow:

```
property var index: null
```

Now in my extension function I expect an object with a variable number of properties, and I set it in the creation of the qml element.